# How to turn the digital pin to analog pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, digital-analog-conversion

I am using a 10 IR sensor array and they use analog pins. I am using a motor shield for the Uno. So I cannot use the Mega. I have only five analog pins I need 8. How can I do it?

Comment: The Mega can take shields made for the Uno.

Comment: you have 6 analog input pins A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5. some Uno clones with SMD ATmega328p have A6, A7 accessible (maybe Robotdyn)

Comment: which sensors are you using? ... how are the sensors connected?

Comment: You might like to use a analog multiplexer.

Comment: Use an I2C or SPI connected ADC chip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external A/D converter, there are a lot of varieties in a lot of price ranges for the Arduino. Check your favorite online source. That will require two of your existing analog pins for the I2C interface but you will gain back many more depending on your choice. If you choose to use SPI that will take 4 pins.